# Simple way to represent force/flow directed, weighted graph?

Tags: d3.js, graph, neo4j, data-visualization

I have a set of weighted pairwise relations between nodes which are all of the same type, like this:

```
A-[1]->B
A-[2]->C
B-[3]->C
B-[2]->D
E-[1]->A
```

I'd like to lay out this graph in such a way that makes the precedence order of the nodes relatively clear (i.e. that "flow" goes roughly from E to A to B/C/D)

I think what I need similar to a [Force Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) but with the added notion of edge weight and directionality

I've looked into using neo4j's builtin viz view and d3 but they don't seem to offer what I need out of the box. Is there a standard approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: Note: the graph isn't guaranteed to be a DAG but there will be a node that can be considered to be at the "top"and I know how to find this node

Comment: Also, the graph may contain hundreds but probably not thousands on nodes and edges

Comment: why dont you just have a directed force layout graph, i.e arrows ? http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278

Comment: @AJ_91: the arrows here help but the underlying force model is still `d3.layout.force`, which only seems to support uniform charge/distance/etc parameters so the layout won't react meaningfully to edge weights. I guess I could mess with line width, though

Comment: Actually, apparently I can't read and linkDistance etc can indeed be specified as a function of the underlying nodes, it just doesn't seem to be used that way in any examples I could find. Awesome!

Comment: So all sorted then ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with Neo4j's built in viz you should be able to do:

```
MATCH path = (a:LabelA {id:"A"})-[:FOO*..10]->()
RETURN path
```

which should show you the tree starting from `A`